# Viewing crash report without play store on device

Tags: android

I haven't added google account into my android device and I installed an off-market apk file (self developed) and it is crashing. The message I see is "Unfortunately  has crashed" with no button to view the stack trace.

Is there a way to see the stack trace of the crash report. I am running 4.2 jelly bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable usb debuging and from the command line do:

```
adb logcat
```

Comment: It works but shows whole system logs. Is it possible to filter adb logs per application as done by eclipse

Comment: You can use eclipse to see the android logs even if your app wasn't started with eclipse.